# My.User.Name vs. My.User.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name

Tags: .net, vb.net

I've found that both My.User.Name and My.User.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name both return the Windows login ID of the user logged in to the PC. However, is there a difference between the two? Will there ever be a case where they won't return the same value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The information on the `My.User` MSDN page has the best summary of these values and when they differ

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3da82hw(VS.80).aspx

In summary though.  The biggest difference occurs between Windows and Web Applications.

> For Windows applications, this property provides the same functionality as the CurrentPrincipal property. For Web applications, this property provides the same functionality as the User property of the object returned by the Current property.

Comment: Thanks. Since I'm using this in a Windows application, I can rest assured that they are the same - and that I can use the shorter of the two :)

Answer (score 2):

<strike>If you are in the context of a `System.Web.UI.Page`, then:</strike>

- `Me.User` returns `Me.Context.User`;
- `Me.Context` returns `HttpContext.Current`

So they are indeed the same thing.

Oops! Read that a bit too quickly. `My` is a "magic shortcut" to some common contextual objects, and `User` is one of them. It is still the same as the expanded form.

Comment: OP say `My` which is very different than `Me`